# @JsonView: different perspectives

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, json-view

I'm coding a Spring Web Service, using Jackson by default. I'm using @JsonView to indicate which property I need to be parsed to my JSON object. So, the problem is: Many objects are used in different classes, but not exactly all its properties, for example:

```
class Professor {
  @JsonView({Views.Public.class, Views.Internal.class})
  private int id;
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  private String name;
  ...
}

class Classroom {
  @JsonView({Views.Public.class, Views.Internal.class})
  private int id;
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  private String name;
  ...
}

class Lecture {
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private Professor professor;
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private Classroom classroom;
  ...
}
```

What if I need more than two 'perspectives', I'd have to create more interfaces/classes to do that? (like Views.Professor, Views.Principal, ...) Is this a real good practice?

I'd like to hear some suggestions or alternatives to solve that. I'm a little bit confused about being on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Generic names

You always can define *more views* if you need *more perspectives*, that's the idea behind the Jackson JSON views and that's what makes it flexible.

If you use *generic names* in your views classes, such as `Basic`, `Extended`, `Public`, `Private` and so on, you'll find it easier to *reuse* them across multiple beans.

### Inheritance

You always can rely on *inheritance* with [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html). Consider the following example where `Views.Private` extends `Views.Public`:

```java
public class Views {
    interface Public {}
    interface Private extends Public {}
}
```

Serialization of properties annotated with `@JsonView(Views.Private.class)` will also include properties annotated with `@JsonView(Views.Public.class)`.

Comment: Thanks! I think using _generic names_ as you said is a better choice, now I need to figure it out which is the best approach for my API. Do you know any others JSON apis that provide something like @JsonView?

Comment: @psi_ Gson is another popular JSON parser for Java, but I'm not sure if it provider something like JSON views.

Comment: @psi_ If my answer works for you, please click the tick next to my answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.. hahaha